# MVC Page Refresh Error - Html.DropDownListFor selection has no effect on items displayed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following jQuery function that makes an AJAX call to display data based on a DropDown selection in the typical MVC cshtml shown in the 2nd code block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#genericDropDown").on("change", function () {
        var text = $("#genericDropDown option:selected").text();
        var options = {
            url: '/pet/index/' + text,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false
        };

        var jqXHR = $.ajax(options);
    });
});
```

This is the cshtml.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
        </tr>

        etc
```

The page starts off with a number of items as a result of selecting all. When I make a selection in the DropDown, I can see in fiddler that it's being picked up okay, and in a typical case only ONE item is selected from the DB to refresh the page with. This works. And when I set a breakpoint in the cshtml, I can see that the foreach loop is iterated through one time only, as expected. However, after the page is refreshed, all items are still there, instead of the one I selected using the DropDown. That's why I set cache to false in the jQuery, and I also tried

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

on the controller action, think that caching was causing this. But still, all items are always displayed. Beats the heck out of me.

Please help.

Comment: only thing looks wierd to me is you use the TEXT of the option, instead its value, err?

Comment: Well, in this case I'm using the text to select from the db. The weird thing is I see the cshtml loop iterated thru just once, but I still have multiple items on the page from the last load. If I enter localhost:54710/Pet/index/toy in the browser, I expect and do see only the single pet product that is a toy. This is what I want to happen with the dropdown...